How to test the abortion of Scheduled Apex?
How do I test a class that aborts scheduled apex jobs?
public class ScheduledJobCleanup implements Schedulable{

    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        for(AsyncApexJob job : [SELECT Id, CronTriggerId FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ApexClass.Name = 'SuppressionScheduler' AND Status = 'Completed']) {
            System.abortJob(job.CronTriggerId);
        }
    }

}

Here is my attempt at testing it. I scheduled the cleanup job later to give the actual jobs time to complete but I guess that doesn't work in the test env.
@isTest public class TestScheduledJobCleanup {

    @isTest
    static void testScheduledJobCleanup() {

        Account a = new Account(Name='Test Schedule');
        Lead l = new Lead(LastName='Test', Company='Test Company');
        insert a;
        insert l;

        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>{a.Id};
        Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>{l.Id};

        String sec = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());
        String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute()); 
        String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour());
        String day = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().day());
        String month = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().month());
        String year = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().year());

        String cronExp = sec + ' ' + min+1 + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ? ' +year;

        SuppressionScheduler ScheduledAccountSuppression = new SuppressionScheduler(accountIds, null, null, null);
        System.schedule('ScheduledAccountSuppression', cronExp, ScheduledAccountSuppression);
        SuppressionScheduler ScheduledLeadSuppression = new SuppressionScheduler(null, null, null, leadIds);
        System.schedule('ScheduledLeadSuppression', cronExp, ScheduledLeadSuppression);

        Test.startTest();
        cronExp = sec + ' ' + min+3 + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ? ' +year;
        ScheduledJobCleanup ScheduledSuppressionJobCleanup = new ScheduledJobCleanup();
        System.schedule('ScheduledSuppressionJobCleanupTest', cronExp, ScheduledSuppressionJobCleanup);
        Test.stopTest();
    }   

}
